# HSI color format in python with opencv library

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, colors

Good morning, I was reviewing in python, along with Opencv, conversions to formats of different colors, but I do not find the HSI format, with the `cv2.cvtColor()` function.

Does anyone know if it matches the `COLOR_BGR2HLS` parameter?

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article given [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), the HSV, HLS and HSI color space terminology can be used interchangeably.

There is another option available in OpenCV as well `cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`.

If you work out both the options, the resulting image would appear slightly different as in the following:

Using HSV:

[image]

Using HLS:

[image]

Now if you split the channels of these images *(to split use `cv2.split()`)* and analyze them:

- The **hue** channel appears to be the same in both cases.
- The **saturation** channel also provides the same result but appear to be switched.
- You will notice a slight difference between the **value** channel of HSV image and the **luminosity** channel of the HLS image.

Work it out for an image and you will see for yourself.

HSV, HLS and HSI are **similar** not exactly **same**